# Fragment doesn't automatically update on clicking

Tags: java, android, fragment, refresh

I have a fragment in my action bar and if the user clicks on the fragment button, the page should automatically update/refresh if there any contents in it. The issue I'm facing is, the fragment doesn't automatically update the first time but updates and refreshes when I press it the second time.

This is the flow:

Choose fragment 1 -> Doesn't update/refresh -> go back and choose another fragment 2 from action bar -> choose fragment 1 again -> Updates the UI of fragment 1.

I'm calling the fragment 1 from MainActivity in the onPostExecute of an Async task.

MainActivity,

```
private final FragmentOne f1 = new FragmentOne();

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            f1.updateUI();
        }
```

I have this piece of code in my fragment class.

```
// Updates the fragment-1 UI
public void updateUI() {
    if (isAdded()) {
        String currentDatabaseName = null;
        hideAllTables();
        hideWarningLabelsAndHeaders();
        progressBarIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (null != getUserIdentifier()) {
            currentDatabaseName = Utils.buildUserDataFromFli(getUserIdentifier());
        }
        if (null != currentDatabaseName) {
            shopData = new ShopDao(ShopApplication.getLoggedInUser(), Utils.getDatabaseIndexMap());
            transcationData = new TranscationDao(ShopApplication.getLoggedInUser(), Utils.getDatabaseIndexMap());
        }
        configureUserDependentFetchers(getUserIdentifier());
    }
}
```

Comment: where you call asyntask?

Comment: Is your `isAdded` boolean updated on the first call?

Comment: check that boolean value is correct or not when the  fragment added

Comment: /**
     * Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.
     */
    final public boolean isAdded() {
        return mActivity != null && mAdded;
    }

Comment: I'm calling the updateUI in my onResume() part of the activity. Could that be the reason @IshitaSinha

Comment: What is `mAdded`? And please edit your question and add that code to the question itself. It is difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, maybe work for you ;)

On Activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        //to send broadcast for refresh
        Intent intentRefresh = new Intent("com.yourapp.REFRESH_DATA");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(YourActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intentRefresh);
    }
```

On Your Fragment :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverMap = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("com.yourapp.REFRESH_DATA")) {
           //put here code for refresh
        }
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    //register your LocalBroadcatManager
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.yourapp.REFRESH_DATA");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiverMap, intentFilter);
    return view;
}
```